# net.rcarz.jiraclient.JiraException: Project or issue type 'Bug' missing from create metadata. Do you have enough permissions?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jira, pom.xml

Facing this issue in jira - Selenium interaction. I am having enough permission to create issue still facing the issue can anyone help me out